# Trying to unit test template-based form in a component, form has no controls

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test a *template-based* form in my component.  The form is simple and contains contact information for a person.  What I'm trying to do is unit test various validation scenarios.  I thought what I could do is simply set a value on, say, email-address and then inspect the ngForm object, obtain the respective formControl for emailAddress and then check for the validity status. However, what I'm finding is that the form, while it exists, it does not contain any controls at all.  So it appears the form is never built entirely.

The code (I've omitted import and some provider statements, etc for brevity):

**person-details-contact-info.component.html**

```html
<custom-input type="text"
            name="emailAddress"
            [(ngModel)]="model.emailAddress"
            maxlength="255"
            pattern="^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$"
            #emailAddress="ngModel">
</custom-input>

<custom-input type="text"
            [disabled]="permissions.canViewOnly"
            name="phone"
            [(ngModel)]="model.phone"
            maxlength="16">
</custom-input>

<custom-input type="text"
            [disabled]="permissions.canViewOnly"
            name="model.fax"
            [(ngModel)]="fax"
            maxlength="16">
</custom-input>
```

**person-details-contact-info.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'person-details-contact-info',
    templateUrl: 'person-details-contact-info.component.html',
    viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
})
export class PersonDetailsContactInfoComponent {

    @Input('model')
    model: {
        emailAddress: '',
        phone: '',
        fax: ''
    }
}
```

** unit test code **

```ts
@Component({
    template: `
        <form #form="ngForm">
            <person-details-contact-info [(model)]="model">
            </person-details-contact-info>
        </form>
    `,
    providers: [ ]
})
export class TestHostComponent {
    model: PersonDetailsContactInfoModel = new PersonDetailsContactInfoModel();

    @ViewChild('form')
    ngForm: NgForm;
}

describe('In the file "person-details-contact-info.component.ts', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
    let component: TestHostComponent;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
            declarations: [TestHostComponent, PersonDetailsContactInfoComponent],
            providers: [ ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('is has invalid email format', () => {
        component.model.emailAddress = 'an invalid email format.';
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const ctrl = component.ngForm.form.get('emailAddress');
        expect(ctrl.valid).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

The above test is wrong because the "ctrl" object is null.  The emailAddress control does not exist within the form.  By the way, this all works fine in the actual component so clearly I'm doing something wrong with the unit test setup.

Lastly, for the sake of understanding the code, the way my app is I've broken up a very large form into separate components.  So this "contact-info" component is a section of a much larger form.  That is why I am binding to a model and providing an existing NgForm in the providers section of the person-details-contact-info.component.  Again, everything works perfectly within the app itself, it's just the way I'm attempting to do my unit testing isn't working out the way I expected.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I figured out what's going on.  What I'm attempting to do will work but within the unit test's "it" block and after "fixture.detectChanges()" I need to then do a "fixture.whenStable()".  For example:

```
it('is has invalid email format', () => {
    component.model.emailAddress = 'an invalid email format.';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const ctrl = component.ngForm.form.get('emailAddress');
        expect(ctrl.valid).toBe(false);
    });        
});
```

This is interesting because I've had a similar issue within the actual app where a component, apparently, isn't "stable".  Trying to immediately access (either within OnInit or AfterViewInit) formControls within a form will result in null objects.

Comment: Why did I forget about "whenStable()"... so much shame :)

Comment: you'll also need to wrap your arrow function in `waitForAsync()`