# How to test template driven forms in angular 6

Tags: angular, testing, angular6

I have a template driven form:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <input class="form-control input-lg" id="venue_name" name="venue_name" type="text" #venue_name="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="tournament.venue.venue_name" required>
      <input id="address" name="address" placeholder="search for location" required #address="ngModel"
             type="text" class="form-control input-lg" #search [(ngModel)]="tournament.venue.address">
</form>
```

In my component, I have:

```
@ViewChild(NgForm) ngForm: NgForm;
```

In my test, I have:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TournamentEditVenueComponent);
comp = fixture.componentInstance;
form = comp.ngForm.form;
console.log(form);
```

Here I can see in Chrome console:

```
FormGroup {venue_name: FormControl, address: FormControl, details: FormControl, country_id: FormControl}
```

So the form seems to be reachable

but when I try to reach it with

```
    console.log(form.controls);
```

or

```
    console.log(form.controls['venue_name']);
```

the first one is empty and the second one is undefined.

Why ? How should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unsure of the exact reasoning for this - Would need to look into how the fixture works more, but the below code worked for me.

For a solution it seems that you don't call `fixture.detectChanges()` once you've done the setup and this is required in your test to set up the data bindings. More info: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Once this is done based on this answer [Trying to unit test template-based form in a component, form has no controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045651/trying-to-unit-test-template-based-form-in-a-component-form-has-no-controls) it explains that they fixed it by then also ensuring that the fixture is stable -

> fixture.whenStable() returns a promise that resolves when the
>   JavaScript engine's task queue becomes empty.

If you try and access the form controls within here then it will work as in the example below.

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TournamentEditVenueComponent);
comp = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();

fixture.whenStable().then( () => {
   console.log(comp.ngForm.controls['venue_name'])
   component.ngForm.controls['venue_name].setValue('test_venue');
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how are you able to access `comp.ngForm`. it's not exposed to directly access like that

Comment: To avoid callback hell in your test cases you can put in your test set a `beforeEach` with `await fixture.whenStable();`.

In that way all your test will be stable and your angular form will be loaded